# elasticsearch php nested aggregations

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I tried searching an trying.
I need to group the nested fields.
The sql query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT p_application_category,
       Sum(p_recv_bytes) as download,
       p_date
    FROM ZLog2 $w
    group by p_application_category;
```

Comment: Could you show your elastic mapping and how you've tried to translate that sql into dsl?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with elastic sql plugin. It makes regular sql statements available in elastic.